# How to solve this system of trigonometric trancendental equations over the reals?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, trigonometry

Namely,

$$\left\{x^2+2 x \sin (y)+3 \cos (y)=0,\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}+\sin (y)\right)=y-\frac{\pi }{3}\right\}$$
My simple-minded trial

```
Reduce[{x^2 + 2x Sin[y] + 3Cos[y] == 0,  ArcSin[x/2 + Sin[y]] == y - Pi/3},
       {x, y}, Reals]
```

is unsuccessful: the command is running for hours, almost crashing my computer.
The plot

```
ContourPlot[{x^2 + 2x Sin[y] + 3Cos[y] == 0, ArcSin[x/2 + Sin[y]] == y - Pi/3}, 
            {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 2Pi}]
```

[image]

demonstrates the only real solution.
It is easy to solve it numerically with

```
FindRoot[{x^2 + 2x Sin[y] + 3Cos[y] == 0, ArcSin[x/2 + Sin[y]] == y - Pi/3}, 
         {{x, 0}, {y, 1}}]
```

> ```
> { x->-1.40126, y->1.31812}
> ```

however I am interested in a symbolic solution. At first sight, I can't see a way to solve this quite nonstandard system
under consideration by hand. Maple 2017.2 cracks it in a moment, outputting
$$  \left\{ x=-2\,\cos \left( \arctan \left( \sqrt {15} \right) +\pi/6
 \right) -1/2\,\sqrt {15},y=\arctan \left( \sqrt {15} \right) 
 \right\} .
$$

Comment: If you take `Sin` of the second equation then the system is much more tractable.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: But not equivalent.

Comment: Yes, true, but easy to filter a afterwards.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Can you kindly elaborate your suggestion, giving an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an extension of my earlier comment.  The solution of the equations, transformed as suggested by [b.gatessucks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/134/b-gatessucks), is

```
s = Reduce[{x^2 + 2*x*Sin[y] + 3*Cos[y] == 0, 
            x/2 + Sin[y] == Sin[y - Pi/3]}, {x, y}, Reals]
(* (C[1] ∈ Integers && ((x == 1/4 (-Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[15]) && 
   y == 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[3/5]] + 2 π C[1]) || (x == 1/4 (-Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[15]) && 
   y == -2 ArcTan[Sqrt[3/5]] + 2 π C[1]))) || (C[1] ∈ Integers && x == Sqrt[3] && 
   y == π + 2 π C[1]) *)
```

Now substitute the first of the three solutions into the original equations

```
FullSimplify[{x^2 + 2*x*Sin[y] + 3*Cos[y] == 0, 
    ArcSin[x/2 + Sin[y]] == y - Pi/3} /. (s[[1, 2, 1]] // ToRules), s[[1, 1]]]
(* {True, C[1] == 0} *)
```

Therefore, the  `C[1] == 0` member of the first family of solutions is valid,

```
({x, y} /. (s[[1, 2, 1]] // ToRules) /. C[1] -> 0)
(* {1/4 (-Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[15]), 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[3/5]]} *)
```

Doing the same with the second family of solutions, however, yields,

```
FullSimplify[{x^2 + 2*x*Sin[y] + 3*Cos[y] == 0, 
    ArcSin[x/2 + Sin[y]] == y - Pi/3} /. (s[[1, 2, 2]] // ToRules), s[[1, 1]]]
(* {True, False} *)
```

and similarly for the third family of solutions.

Note that the one valid solution is equivalent to that from Maple.

```
FullSimplify[({x, y} /. (s[[1, 2, 1]] // ToRules) /. C[1] -> 0) == 
    {-2 Cos[ArcTan[Sqrt[15]] + Pi/6] - Sqrt[15]/2, ArcTan[Sqrt[15]]}]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 12):

`Sin` is defined in the whole complex plane, while `ArcSin` is not. Solving a system involving `ArcSin` makes unneccessary problems therefore it is better to use `Sin` instead `ArcSin`.  Let's take a look at this:

```
ContourPlot[{x^2 + 2x Sin[y] + 3Cos[y] == 0, x/2 + Sin[y] == Sin[y - Pi/3]}, 
            {x, -25, 25}, {y, -5 Pi, 5 Pi}]
```

[image]

We can see there are infinitely many solutions, however one seems to ask about the only one solution equivalent to that observed with `ContourPlot` involving `ArcSin`. Thus we are interested in solutions `-4<= x <=4` and `-1 <= y - Pi/3 <= 1`. We are solving the system without `ArcSin` (it make the problem easier) however we have to add appropriately modified restriction on variables `x` and `y`:

```
sol = {x, y} /. { ToRules @ Reduce[{x^2 + 2x Sin[y] + 3Cos[y] == 0, 
                                    x/2 + Sin[y] == Sin[y - Pi/3],
                                    -4 <= x <= 4,
                                    -1 <= y - Pi/3 <= 1},
                                   {x, y}]}
```

> ```
> {{1/4 (-Sqrt[3] - Sqrt[15]), 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[3/5]]}}
> ```

```
ContourPlot[{x^2 + 2 x Sin[y] + 3 Cos[y] == 0, ArcSin[x/2 + Sin[y]] == y - Pi/3},
            {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.025], Point[sol]}, ContourStyle -> Thick,
    PlotPoints -> 25, MaxRecursion -> 4, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your realization of the idea suggested by @b.gatesucks. Can you base your statement "So we are interested in solutions $-5\le x \le5 $and $0 \le y \le 2\pi$"? You solve a different system which is not equivalent to the assigned one. AFAIKI,the original system has the unique real solution (and a lot of complex solutions).

Comment: @user64494  You are correct.  Substituting the three solutions into the original equations shows that only one is valid.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: The transformed system has infinite number of real solutions. The point is how to select (with Mathematica, not by hand) the only right one.

Comment: @user64494  The three solutions of the transformed equation contains `C[1]`, with `C[1]` an integer.  Hence, there are three infinite families of solutions.  Substitute each of the three solutions into the original equations to obtain `{True, C[1] == 0}`  for one family and `{True, False}` for the others.  I can provide more detail, if desired.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: It would be kind of you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the upvotes  is mine.

Comment: @user64494  Asking a question you should first clearly state your problem. `Sin` is a well defined function, `ArcSin` makes sense only localy. This is why the system works with troubles when we have `ArcSin`.