# Solve can't solve my trigonometric equation—why?

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions, trigonometry

I have the following equation for epsilon

$2 |\alpha_{n,ch}|=\epsilon+\cos^{-1}(\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\epsilon}{2}))$, where $\alpha_{n,ch}$ is a negative constant (e.g. -0.769)

I tried to solve it using both `Solve` and `NSolve`:

```
Solve[{-2 anch == eps + ArcCos[Tan[Pi/4 - eps/2]]}, eps]
```

but some error occurred:

> Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.

And

```
NSolve[{-2 anch == eps + ArcCos[Tan[Pi/4 - eps/2]]}, eps]
```

just returns itself as a result

So, what can I do, to solve this equation?

Comment: To symbolic solvers apply exact numbers and we have to restrict `eps`, e.g. `With[{anch = -769/1000}, Solve[{-2 anch == eps + ArcCos[Tan[Pi/4 - eps/2]], -3 < eps < 3}, eps] // Quiet]` yields an exact solution.

Comment: While using exact values is often a good idea, it is not necessary in this case. The key is putting bounds on `eps` as @Artes did; either `Solve` or `NSolve` will work with an inexact value for `anch`.

Comment: @Artes maybe I put it not quite correctly, `anch` is not a constant that I can define just for this equation, I obtain it from another math expression and therefore I can't predict good restriction for epsilon. And I can't believe that Mathematica can't solve it without any restrictions on epsilon

Comment: @BobHanlon I'm using version `11.2`, it seems that since version `12.0` `Solve` automatically switches to `NSolve`. Even though they are internally  related, `Solve` usually did not work with numerical input before version `12.0`, as in my case here. Am I right?

Comment: @Artes - I do not have access to any versions prior to 12.0; however, I would expect `Solve` to rationalize the input if it could not solve with the inexact input (with the appropriate warning). The bounds on `eps` would be needed. You should be able to determine with your version.

Comment: @BobHanlon As I've said `Solve` simply does not work, `Solve[{eqs[-0, 769], -3 < eps < 3}, eps]` remains unevaluated in `ver.11.2` and it's ever been  like this. I usually try to provide answers with the conditions as week as possible. Nonetheless I guess that  automatic rationalizing numerical input wouldn't be a convenient idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Solve`, `NSolve` as well as `FindRoot` can solve this equation, one should only remember several issues which may appear to be critical in different cases.

First let's define two different functions,  they are equivalent on appropriate subsets of the space of variables `{anch, eps}`.

```
 eqs[anch_]:= -2 anch == eps + ArcCos[Tan[π/4 - eps/2]]
 eqsC[anch_]:= Cos[-2 anch - eps] ==  Tan[π/4 - eps/2]
```

`NSolve` may be regarded a numerical counterpart of `Solve`, and so it is natural to restrict the variable `eps`.

```
NSolve[{eqs[-0.769], -3 < eps < 3}, eps]
```

> ```
> {{eps -> 0.556395}}
> ```

in case of `FindRoot` one has to set an appropriate starting point:

```
FindRoot[eqs[-0.769], {eps, 0}]
```

> ```
> {eps -> 0.556395}
> ```

```
With[{anch = -(769/1000)}, 
  Plot[2 anch + eps + ArcCos[Tan[π/4 - eps/2]], {eps, -6, 6}]]
```

[image]

It is a good habit to use exact numbers in symbolic solvers using e.g. `Rationalize` on inexact numbers.  Another issue is using `ArcCos` (it has a bounded domain) in `Solve` what necessarily implies certain problems, see e.g. . One can restrict `eps` e.g. [How to solve this system of trigonometric trancendental equations over the reals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155649/how-to-solve-this-system-of-trigonometric-trancendental-equations-over-the-reals/155664#155664)

```
 Solve[{eqs[-769/1000], -3 < eps < 3}, eps] // Quiet
```

> ```
>  {{eps -> Root[{-(769/500) + ArcCos[Tan[π/4 - #1/2]] + #1 &, 
>                   0.556395249766362049415258676637}]}}
> ```

Alternatively we can rewrite the equation, then there are inifintely many solutions, even in the real domain:

```
eps /. Solve[eqsC[-769/1000], eps, Reals]
```

[image]

```
With[{anch = -769/1000}, 
  Plot[-Cos[-2 anch - eps] + Tan[π/4 - eps/2], {eps, -10, 14}]]
```

[image]

If we change `anch` we should also enlarge the range where  we are going to search for solutions, e.g.

```
 Solve[{eqs[-3149/1000], -8 < eps < 8}, eps] // Quiet
```

> ```
>   {{eps -> Root[{-(3149/500) + ArcCos[Tan[π/4 - #1/2]] + #1 &, 
>       6.28329345234967439849595819061}]}}
> ```

We can also demonstrate solutions of our equations for various values of `anch` with `ContourPlot` what can be used when searching for exact solutions with `Solve` (or `Reduce`) or aprropriate starting point in `FindRoot`:

```
GraphicsRow[
  ContourPlot[#, {anch, -16, 8}, {eps, -15, 15}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> Thick] & /@ 
      {eqsC[anch], eqs[anch]}]
```

[image]

Comment: ok, it works for `anch = -769 / 1000`, but I can't get result for `anch = -3149 / 1000` (too long evaluation, i aborted it).

Comment: maybe there is some bug in my Mathematica version, but the last example stops working(very long evaluation) if I change `eps` range, for example, to `-13<eps<13`. Or it is normal?

Comment: @timbars In case `-13 < eps < 13` it is better to use `eqsC` defined in my answer because `Solve` doesn't work seemlessly with functions like `ArcCos`, see e.g. this answer [How to solve this system of trigonometric trancendental equations over the reals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155649/how-to-solve-this-system-of-trigonometric-trancendental-equations-over-the-reals/155664#155664)

Comment: ok, thanks for your detailed answer